# Jquery address plugin - history (back/forward) tracking not working

Tags: jquery, url-rewriting, navigation, history, jquery-address

I have been trying to get the Jquery address plugin to work properly for about 12 hours now, thus I figured its time to post. The problem I have is that the back and forward navigation is not working. IE: click on a link and then click the back button does not actually navigate back. It changes the url though. The other thing which leads me to believe I am doing something fundamentally wrong is I have inserted the `$.address.title($(this).attr("title"));` and it does not actually change the address.

Jquery here:

```
$('#swNavlist a').address(); 
$('#swNavlist a').click(function() {

    $("#swBody").block({ 
    message:"Loading",
    css: { 
        border: 'none', 
        padding: '15px', 
        backgroundColor: '#000', 
        '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
        '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
        opacity: .5, 
        color: '#fff' 
    } });


    var content_show = $(this).attr("href").replace(/^#/, '');


    $.ajax({
        method: "get",url: content_show,
        //"+bvLanguage+"/

        success: function(html){ //so, if data is retrieved, store it in html

            $("#swBody").html(html); //show the html inside .content div
            $("#swBody").unblock();
            $.address.title($(this).attr("title"));


        },//success
        error: function(){
            $("#swBody").unblock();
            $("#swBody").block({ 
                message:"Error Encountered",
                css: { 
                    border: 'none', 
                    padding: '15px', 
                    backgroundColor: '#000', 
                    '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
                    '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
                    opacity: .5, 
                    color: '#fff' 
                }, 
                timeout:1000
            })  
        }   
    }); //close $.ajax(
    $("#swNavlist").topZIndex();

});//end navigation
```

HTML here:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <Title>Swebits Home</title>
    <link href="css/swCss.css" rel="styleSheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.pngFix.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.blockUI.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.topzindex.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sw.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.address-1.3.2.min.js?autoUpdate=1"></script>



</head>

<body>
        <div id="swHead">
            <div class="leftCol"></div>
            <div class="centerCol">


                <div class="navigation">
                    <ul id="swNavlist">
                        <li id="active"><a href="#home.html" id="current" title="Swebits Home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#webd.html" title="Swebits Web Development">Web Design</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#bla.html" title="webs.html">Web Systems</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" title="hosting.html">Hosting</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" title="photo.html">Photography</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" title="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" title="network.html">Our Network</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" title="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rightCol"></div>
        </div>
    <div id="swContainer" class="clearfix">


        <div id="swCenter" class="clearfix">


            <div id="swBody">
                <?php
                    include("home.html");
                ?>
            </div>

            <div id="swFooter">

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Lastly I tried to implement an if statement so that if the target is blank the page redirects to 'error.html' but that did not appear to work either.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: I am short on time and may have misunderstood what you're doing, so I am not posting this as an answer. If I understand your goals correctly, I believe the absolute best plugin for you to use is http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

This plugin seems to be doing same as many other history/hash plugins. However as per [asual.com](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/express/) examples - he does call the init() function, even though the docs say you don't have to.

View the source of that and see if some things are documented improperly

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing, It seams you are loading the pages yourself (through a click event triggered function) what you need to do in create a function triggered by the JQ address event `change` and inside that use the JQ Address `value` attribute (deep linking value after `#`) to set the correct page to be loaded with AJAX.

Right now you are telling JQ Address what your current page state is but you are not telling it what to do with that value, you are insted making the changes yourself so JQ Address can't make them when you enter the right URL or use the back forward buttons.